# Accessing mysql database created in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Using Windows 7. Installed Apache, MySQL, php with XAMPP. Using XAMPP I created a new database SCP and successfully imported data into it. It shows in the left panel along with the ones such as "test" that came with the installation. I can examine its structure etc. in XAMPP. When I am in XAMPP it shows me a root@localhost.

How do I now browse to it, something like http://localhost/something, I suppose. And how do I control what user/password I am if I don't want to be root when I open it in my browser?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Normally you want a database as a place to store data for an application -- either a prebuilt application (like phpBB or WordPress or OpenCart or whatever) or a custom application you write to do whatever you want. Your application can be a web application or native to your system. You don't directly access the database and it's generally a bad idea to allow your users direct access anyway. Does that help at all?

Comment: Thanks Isaac. Sorry for the confused question. Yes, that helps, and I have solved the particular problem that caused me to make that post. I'm just beginning to look at database stuff.